# Problemas al deserializar Json en xamarin

Tags: c#, rest, xamarin

Hola tengo un problema a la hora de consumir datos de una api rest.
Tengo la siguiente clase:

```
public partial class Assignee
{
    [JsonProperty("self")]
    public Uri Self { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("accountId")]
    public string AccountId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("emailAddress")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("avatarUrls")]
    public Urls AvatarUrls { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("displayName")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("active")]
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("timeZone")]
    public TimeZone TimeZone { get; set; }
}
```

Y nada más arrancar quiero que me devuelva por ejemplo el email y lo intento así:

```
private const string Url = "https://xxx.xxx/res/apixxx.json";
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        var client = new RestClient(Url);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "683c-b7567-42c-8dea-f90f567");
        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic Yyryrty56456JG");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        var content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Assignee>(response.Content); 

        LblText.Text = content.EmailAddress;
    }
```

Creo que no tengo muy claro el tema de Deserializar un json, Visual Studio no me devuelve ningún error, pero no me muestra nada por pantalla, alguién sabe en que estoy fallando?
Gracias.

Comment: y esta llegando algo a ese metodo?

Comment: Si, puedo traerme el json completo, pero necesito quedarme sólo con algunos campos y es ahí donde no se como hacerlo, o por lo menos no me sale.

Comment: que tiene content? debugueaste a ver cual era su contenido?

Comment: verificaste en la consola del navegador que no te está generando algún error?

Comment: response.Content es el json completo. Si imprimo sólo content me devuelve APIrest.Model.Assignee que es mi clase, y en la consola no veo ningún error

Comment: si pones un breakpoint en el codigo he inspeccionas la variable content despues de deserializar, que valores observas ? porque quizas no es un problema del json o la deserializacion, sino de como vinculas el dato a la UI ese binding quizas no se este realizando de forma correcta

Comment: Según el breakpoint me dice que content es nulo y me muestra esto: No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'System.RuntimeType' al tipo 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.TypeMirror'.

Comment: Alguien tiene alguna idea de que puede estar pasando???